# Controlling `install` permission for automatically created directories?

Tags: linux, permissions

is it possible to create directories when the same permissions using `install`?

for example

```
$ ls -la /srv
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root  202 2024-02-01 15:07 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root  226 2024-02-01 15:12 ..
$ sudo install -g http -m 0750 -d /srv/a/b/c
$ ls -la /src/a/b/c/
drwxr-x--- 1 root http  202 2024-02-01 15:07 .
...
$ ls -la /src/a/b
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root  202 2024-02-01 15:07 .
```

Here `install` did create the intermediate dirs, but completely ignored `-m` and `-g` for them. I can probably work around `-m` being ignored with `umask`, but can't think of something that would work for `-g`. I could run the command as different user which defaults to that, but that would not allow to create as owner root, etc.

Comment: Just `sudo chown -R root:http /srv/a/b/c` afterwards.  Like `sudo install -g http -m 0750 -d /srv/a/b/c && sudo chown -R root:http /srv/a/b/c`

Comment: @JayCravens this will also change permissions of files (which should be `-m 0640`), which can be done with two `find -type ... -exec chmod` etc etc. But asking explicitly about `install`, since it can create the dirs and set permissions, seems like a bad omission not having a way to handle dirs it create.

Comment: You are correct.  The way to it is `sudo find /srv/a/b/c -type d -exec chown root:http {} \;
`  As far as `install`, I couldn't say why that is, but I see what you're saying,